# Deadlocked program using pthread condition variables, critical sections [C++]

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock, critical-section

What I'm trying to do is have each thread copy information from a struct in main using a critical section before main changes the struct for other threads.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

struct foo
{
public:
   int var;
   int *turn;
   int index;
   pthread_mutex_t *bsem;
   pthread_cond_t *waitTurn;
};
void *threadFunc(void *arg) {
    int var;
    foo *workingVar = (foo *)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(workingVar->bsem);
    while (*workingVar->turn != workingVar->index)
        pthread_cond_wait(workingVar->waitTurn, workingVar->bsem);
    var = workingVar->var;
    *workingVar->turn++;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(workingVar->waitTurn);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(workingVar->bsem);
    cout << var << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
int main() {
   int turn = 0, NTHREADS = 5;
   foo mainStruct;
   pthread_mutex_t bsem;
   pthread_mutex_init(&bsem, NULL);
   pthread_cond_t waitTurn = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
   mainStruct.bsem = &bsem;
   mainStruct.waitTurn = &waitTurn;
   mainStruct.turn = &turn;
   pthread_t tid[NTHREADS];
   for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
   mainStruct.index = i;
   mainStruct.var = i;
   pthread_create(&tid[i], nullptr, threadFunc, &mainStruct);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}
```

The code above is from a thread function. I'm trying to make threads wait until it is their 'turn' using pthread_cond_wait, and then once the condition is true, the struct info passed from main will be copied into local variables and will increment the turn and exit the critical section (also not using global variables, so mutex and condition variable is passed using a pointer through the struct). Turn is initialized to 0, and index is the thread number (in the order of which it was created).

This process is deadlocked, and times out.

Please let me know if any more context/information is needed, this is my first Stack Overflow question.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles alright I think changed it to a minimal reproducible example? Ty for the info

Comment: No, that is not a [mre], how is this function called? What is the definition of `foo`? How is `foo` initialised?

Comment: Why this question has tag `C++`? This code is pure `C`!

Comment: To provide [mcve] you can use some online site like [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zvTd3Gzqd) or [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) or ... . "Complete" means we just can copy paste example and compile and run it without filling blanks, so if you use online compiler then you are proving it compiles and runs.

Comment: @MarekR Alright I made a copy paste minimal example, do you mind checking it out/vote for reopen?

Comment: You've messed up priority of operators, should be: `(*workingVar->turn)++;` leading to UB - after fix still there is a dead lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see race condition on `mainStruct.index`. Main thread  modifies it without lock and multiple threads are accessing it under a lock. So if first thread starts fast it will interact with your loop spawning threads.

Looks like you plan was to have multiple instances of `Foo`, but you have one. So imagine scenario:

1. Main thread reaches first join
2. Other threads were created, but didn't start ruinng yet
3. At that point value of `mainStruct.index` is `4`!
4. First thread starts executing and acqurie lock.
5. `turn` is `0` and  `workingVar->index` is `4` (see point 3)
6. So threads enters pthread_cond_wait and waits
7. Next thread executes same as points 4-6
8. Same for other threads
9. All side threads are in waiting state

All threads are waiting no one has called  `pthread_cond_broadcast`
condition `*workingVar->turn != workingVar->index` is always `true`

Also your code is written in `C` not in `C++`. The only `C++` is use of `std::cout`!. Try rewrite this using `std::thread` and it will fix itself (if you pas arguments by values).

[Here is my C++ version](https://godbolt.org/z/GxhEv7KjE)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just didn't see the race condition that helped a lot. I have to use pthreads for this, but I got the point you were trying to convey, so I appreciate it!

Comment: race condition is one of the problems. More important is that you share between threads something what was not planed to share: `workingVar->index`!